# How to access nested object in empty object in javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

// this is model .  i want to access merchant_reference_number. Depend on this i want to update settlement_status to true.

```
    body: {
       code: {type: String},
       message : {type: String},
       status_code: {type: String},
       yes_reference_number: {type: String},
       merchant_reference_number: {type: String},
       amount:{type: Number},
       status: {type: String},
       error: {type: String}

    },

    settlement_status: {type: Boolean , default: false},
    billDate: {type: Date},
    bewo_ret_settlement_id: {type:String},
```

//function for update

```
TransactionSettlement: function(req, res, next) {

    req.params.created_by = req.user._id;

     var filter = {};

     filter.body.merchant_reference_number = { $in: req.params.refnos };
```

// here error comes : Cannot set property 'merchant_reference_number' of undefined

```
            Merchant.findOne({ "body.merchant_reference_number": obj.refnos }).exec(function(err, doc) {

                console.log('err', err);
                console.log('doc', doc);
                doc.bewo_ret_settlement_id = obj.bewo_ret_settlement_id;
                doc.settlement_status = true;


                doc.save();
                res.send(doc);

            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an object first, prior to assign a property to it. In this case, you could do this:

```
filter.body = {};
filter.body.merchant_reference_number = { $in: req.params.refnos };
```

Comment: one more doubt . if i want to search using  status_code in same model?